# PHP Remove Brackets on outside of string

Tags: php, replace, str-replace, brackets, outer-join

I need to remove the outside brackets of a string, but not the inside ones.

For example:

```
"(-58)"         -> "-58"
"('test')"      -> "'test'"
"('st())"       -> "st()"
" (hd)h(l() ) " -> "hd)h(l() "  --> removed all chars up to the bracket
```

Hopefully you can see what I mean.

I know how to remove all the brackets inside a string, but am not sure how to remove just the first and last ones. I also need it to remove all the chars UP TO the bracket, as there could be a space before/after the bracket which I do not want.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you only want to remove spaces before/after the brackets or all characters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use [`preg_replace()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php). This regex replaces leading and trailing brackets (only one) and spaces according to your examples:

```
/(^\s*\()|(\)\s*$)/
```

You can use it like this:

```
$string = ' (hd)h(l() ) ';
$pattern = '/(^\s*\()|(\)\s*$)/';
$replacement = '';
echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacement, $string); // Output: "hd)h(l() "
```

Answer (score 1):

Using php's `trim()` may lead to unexpected over-matching.  Consider the following implementation:

```
$strings=[
    "(-58)",               // -> "-58"
    "('test')",            // -> "'test'"
    "('st())",             // -> "st()"
    " (hd)h(l() ) ",       // -> "hd)h(l() "  --> removed all chars up to the bracket
    " ((2x parentheses))"  // -> assumed to be "(2x parentheses)"
];

foreach($strings as  $s){
    // use double trim() to strip leading/trailing spaces, then parentheses
    var_export(trim(trim($s,' '),'()'));
    echo "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
'-58'
'\'test\''
'\'st'
'hd)h(l() '
'2x parentheses'  // notice this string had two sets of parentheses removed!
```

---

Although several string manipulating functions *could* be used to generate the desired string, using regex is a more direct approach.

Given the following input data:

```
(-58)
('test')
('st())
 (hd)h(l() ) 
 ((2x parentheses))
```

Gergo's pattern will accurately replace the desired characters with and empty string in **261 steps**.

I would like to suggest a more efficient and brief pattern with equivalent accuracy given the OP's sample strings.

```
/^ ?\(|\) ?$/   #142 steps
```

[Demo Link](https://regex101.com/r/OZuJN6/1)

Enhancements:

1. Capture groups are not needed for the pipe to separate the two alternatives.  (improves efficiency and brevity)
2. Replace white-space character `\s` with literal space character. (improves brevity *and potentially accuracy)
3. Reduce quantifier on spaces from `zero or more` to `zero or one`. (more literal to sample data)

Answer (score -1):

You can use trim() function as shown below

```
    $a="(-58)";
    $str=trim($a,"()");
    echo $str;
```